# No-Ip updates the IP address but doesn't point to the host

Tags: networking, server, dns

I'm trying to set up a little server at my home and I need a static hostname in order to make it reachable. To do that, I'm using No-Ip. I've created an account, selected a hostname, and installed and configured de client in my machine. If I use the ping command with the hostname, I get my IP address, and when it changes , it gets updated as well in the No-IP website. But for some reason, the hostname doesn't point to my server. For example, I can't use it in order to access via SSH from outside of my local network; if I go to the hostname with a browser outside of my local network, my website doesn't load either.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have port forwarding set up in your router?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about IPv4 or IPv6? Why do you assume that it's *your* IP(v4) address?

At first you should ask your provider if you are allowed to host a server¹ for private use and if that is even possible. Some providers have [scenarios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) where they do NAT for all customers on their side and don't take any effort to make it work like in the old days, so you won't be able to access any service you host. Some other providers will initially NAT every new modem that connects to their network, but lift restrictions for those who need it, i.e. when I reset one of my boxes with its provided modem installation code I'll have to wait a day or so to be able to access my services.

Once you have confirmation that the provider will reserve an IP only for you you can start setting up UFW on your Ubuntu host and port forwarding or exposed hosts on all the routers you may have and probably didn't know about.

If you're not 100% sure that you're accessing only your computer via an IP only assigned to you you're doing something which computer illiterate people – among them some judges – call hacking or computer fraud.

---

1. Instead of *server* say you want to configure your gaming console with open or type 1 NAT.